# how to overwrite array data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var newSections = Object.assign(this.state.sections)
```

when I do the following it overwrites the entire array

```
newSections=[{title:'primary',data: [...(this.state.sections[0].data),this.state.input] }]
```

I need to only overwrite newSections[0] but the following doesn't work:

```
newSections[0]=[{title:'primary',data: [...(this.state.sections[0].data),this.state.input] }]
```

is that because newSections is immutable?  How to fix?

UPDATE: here’s what I’m trying to do:

```
state={show:true,key:’’,sections: [{title:’primary’,
data:[‘a’,’b’]},
{title:’test’,data:[1,2]},]}
```

I need to add elements to the data arrays and I need to add 
Objects to the sections array

Comment: `Object.assign` shallowly works on Objects.  Is `this.state.sections` an Object or an Array?  Additionally, `Object.assign` takes at least 2 parameters, the target and a number of sources.

Comment: Your top example using Object.assign would make newSections an object. Your bottom 2 lines make newSections an array containing a single object. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @zero298 I would imagine the OP meant to say `Object.assign(...this.state.sections)` but not positive.

Comment: @mhodges What if `this.state,sections` is indeed an array, wouldn't that make `newSections` an array as well?

Comment: @J.Pichardo True.. IMO this question is "Unclear what you are asking"

Comment: @mhodges yeah, OP it would be great if you could give us some context onto what it `this.state.sections`

Answer (score 0):

if you have object

```
var newSections = Object.assign({}, this.state.sections);
```

if you have array

```
var newSections = [].concat(this.state.sections);
```